# Simple vertical multilevel menu

Tags: css, menu, submenu

I am looking for some really simple vertical multilevel menu, but I did not find anything. My idea of menu is for example like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
<li class="parent"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
```

And I would like to at first hide all sub categories. And if I click on the some category, the page will load and one the category with class="parent" will show its category. My question is, how can I reach this only with css?

Answer (score 2):

This is basically how a hover menu works; hide the `<ul>` by default and show it when being hovered.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHfLL/)

```
#menu li > ul {
    display:none;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

If you want `.parent` to show as well just put it in with the hover rule:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHfLL/1/)

```
#menu li:hover > ul,
#menu li.parent > ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu ul li ul {display: none;}
#menu ul li.parent ul {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

to hide the sub categories you need to add these to css file

```
#menu li > ul { display:none;}
```